# Encoding Gmail API Message class into Raw format

Tags: java, gmail, gmail-api

I am using the GMail API in Java and have an issue.

I have the following code:

```
Message message = new Message();

m.setPayload(*set the message part*)
// setter code for Message ommited for brevity

service.users().messages().send("me", m).execute()
```

This gives me back an error message saying:

`Required parameter Message.getRaw() must be specified`

My question is; how can I take the `Message` instance from Gmail and encode it in a base64, URLStringSafe format?

Comment: An answer provided, if it suits you requirement please consider to upvote and accept it, otherwise feel free to leave comment, i will gladly try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You asked

> How can I take the Message instance from Gmail and encode it in a base64, URLStringSafe format

As the place there is no specification of data type of your message payload let imagine we have [MimeMessage](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending) instance, use `ByteArrayOutputStream` and `Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString()` to extract URLStringSafe format.

```html
public Message publishMessage(MimeMessage mime){
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    mime.writeTo(buffer);
    byte[] bytes = buffer.toByteArray();
    Message message = new Message();
    message.setRaw(Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(bytes));

    //some optional operation on your message perhaps
    ...

    return message;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I guess the reason why I want `Message` rather than `MimeMessage` as `Message` seems to be the default deserialization object when you call `service.users().messages().get("me", m_id)`. If i want to mutate that message and then re-send it, It would be useful to keep it as a `Message` object rather than turning it into MimeMessage first, then re-encoding it. Sorry for the long message